# How to call this method from another method?

Tags: objective-c

I realise this may be a very basic question but i'm struggling to understand how to call this method;

```
- (NSString *)findOrCreateDirectory:     (NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPathDirectory inDomain:(NSSearchPathDomainMask)domainMask appendPathComponent:(NSString *)appendComponent
error:(NSError **)errorOut
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was doing just this but my call had a typo. I have another problem now as i'm calling this from another class and I get a "use of an undeclared identifier searchPathDirectory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self findOrCreateDirectory:searchPathDirectory inDomain:domainMask appendPathComponent:appendComponent error:errorOut];
```

It's the way.

Comment: better to show what is `errorOut` and remove the cast

Comment: @BryanChen Check the original post. It is a `NSError **` type.

Answer (score 0):

If the two methods are in the same object.
Then you would do this:

```
-(void)firstMethod {
    [self findOrCreateDirectory:searchPathDirectory inDomain:domainMask appendPathComponent:appendComponent error:errorOut];
}
```

If you have any questions just comment.